# Netlify CMS collection only visible locally

Tags: nunjucks, netlify-cms, eleventy

I have several collections with my Netlify CMS site, all worked fine, but needed to add a new one which is not working on the live site.

I’ve added a new collection to the config file, which works flawlessly in a local environment (I can see the content of the folder referenced in the CMS, all entries are editable, I can create new ones or delete them) but this new collection shows up empty in the live environment - no entries are visible in the live CMS.

I got no error in the console, no build errors either.

I’ve tried to create an entry on the live site, which shows up in the CMS, but not on the site itself, and when I pull it, the newly created page/.md is not getting added to the folder where the other entries are - cannot be found locally.
The site itself displays the content of the folder - all articles show up on the site that were visible in the local CMS environment.

The newly created collection is a copy of a working one (tried it multiple times with different naming) and no matter how I renamed it, each try produced the same result - shows up locally, not in the live CMS.

Any ideas what should I do to display the content of the folder in the live CMS?

a trimmed version of the config file:

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: main
media_folder: "public/logos"
public_folder: "/logos"
logo_url: "/img/cb_logo.svg"
local_backend: true
collections:
  - name: "review"
    editor:
      preview: false
    label: "Reviews"
    folder: "src/review"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Page Title", name: "pagetitle", widget: "string", hint: "Displayed in browser tabs", default: "placeholder text" }
      - {label: "Page meta description", name: "pagemeta", widget: "string", required: false } 

  - name: "article" 
    editor:
      preview: false
    label: "Articles"
    folder: "src/article"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - {label: "Title for Page URL", name: "title", widget: "string", default: "url-friendly-text" }
      - {label: "Page Title", name: "pagetitle", widget: "string", default: "placeholder text" }
```

"Articles" is the one that shows as an empty collection on the live site.
The project folder structure:

```
src/ 
  _data/
  _includes/
  assets/
  article/
  review/
```

Comment: It's gonna be tricky to help without any code to look at. If you can, please attach things like your config file, folder structure, etc.

Comment: I've updated the question, I'm not sure it helps much though - copy-pasting a working collection and renaming it results with the same issue.

Folder and files are in place, works 100% locally (entries show up, can be edited, create new ones without any problem, can delete existing ones).

Comment: ive connected the site to cloudcannon, and it seems like its a netlify cms issue - cloudcannon sees the collection (it has other issues, but it was built for netlify cms, so thats okayish i guess).
Netlify CMS does not have any form of support. They do mention it in the subscription plans that you get email support, but you actually dont. Ive learned this from the netlify people themselves, if you are stuck for a reason that is caused by netlify bad luck.